# Changing the case of the Nth character of a filename using Bash?

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

I have a folder of files and I want to change the case of one of their characters at the 5th position.

From this:

```
ABC-xyz
DEF-xyz
GHI-xys
```

To this:

```
ABC-Xyz
DEF-Xyz
GHI-Xys
```

You'll notice the X has been converted to uppercase.

Any ideas how I'd do this in Bash?

Comment: Are the filenames actually in that pattern, so the letter that needs to change the case is after a `-`? And do you want *just* bash, or are other common *nix utilities like sed etc. fine too?

Comment: Any common utilities which can be invoked from bash would be fine. And yes the files, in this case, are in that pattern!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure bash example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *; do
  g="${f::4}"  ##Split the first four characters
  h="${f:4:1}" ##just the fifth character (starts counting at 0)
  i="${f:5}"   ## character 6+ (again, counting from 0)
  mv -- "$f" "$g${h^^}$i"
    ##At the end, put the strings back together
    ##but make $h (character 5) uppercase
done
exit 0
```

In reality, I would probably use perl-rename (called `rename` in the Ubuntu repos; I know that in some others it goes by `prename`):

```
rename 's/(.{4})(.)/$1\u$2/' *
```

Comment: The rename option looks very elegant. Thank you.